# Cross Project Reference - XCODE 4

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I have a project created in xcode. I want to use this project as a reference in another project. How will I achieve it. Its not a framework or anything. I looked at cross project reference but I am not finding anything in specific or in detail to do it in XCODE 4. It would be helpful if anybody can share information on this. I am totally stuck.

Thanks

Comment: Does the project you want to include produce a lib as output? If yes then you'll have to add this `myLib.lib` to the "Link with libraries" section of the project that includes the other project.

Comment: No it doesn't. Its just a project which has few classes with common methods that can be reused for other applications.

Comment: I guess that projects with such common code should be in a library proejct since this is afaik. the encouraged mecanism for sharing code. So create a new iOS Library project add all "common-code-files" to this project. Then drag this prject to the other project and make sure You add the build product as a dependency in the build phases settings of the main project. This should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you have both projects open. Just drag one project from the project navigator to the project navigator of the other project.
Or did you try that already and it didn't work?

Comment: Yes I tried that already and tried based on the below link. http://liebke.github.com/restkit-github-client-example/  I get error like the header is not found.

Comment: what header is not found? is the header referenced by the parent project or by the child project?

Comment: lexical or preprocessor issue file not found

Comment: yes, but where is that header? and where should it be? what project does import it from which project?

Comment: Error comes in the child project. Eg #import <Common/ColorButton.h> I get error in this line. Common is the parent project

Comment: Well id doesn't work this way. You can't include stuff from the parent project in the child project. It work's only the other way around. Parent can use stuff from the child.

Comment: Common is just a project which has few classes with common methods that can be reused for other applications. In my other application I have referenced Common project. Is that correct.

Comment: That's correct. Have you tried to play around with the path? using just #import "ColorButton.h" etc?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my own question in Xcode 4.2.1 for iOS 5. When one project is referencing another project you have to use absolute path names.